# Jinja2 Ansible Template - Need help removing decimal from a variable

Tags: templates, ansible, decimal, jinja2, rounding

I am trying to build a configuration file for an application that will pull the ansible_memtotal_mb variable and take 50% of that value and use it for the server process.  The challenge is that the math inevitably returns a decimal.  The application config file does not like the decimal place so i need to get rid of that.  Here is a sample of what I am trying to do.   Where percona_memory_pool = "{{ ansible_memtotal_mb * ram_multiplier }}"

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = {% if (percona_memory_pool|int >= 16384) %} {{ (percona_memory_pool|int/8192)|round }}
{% else %} 8
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to make sure the final result is transformed to an int and not a float which will display with a decimal point.

Here is an example only using filters. (Note: I did not change you logic for calculation but it does not look like it gives a coherent result)

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{
          (percona_memory_pool | int >= 16384)
          | ternary((percona_memory_pool | int / 8192), 8)
          | round
          | int
        }}"
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e percona_memory_pool=16383

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "8"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e percona_memory_pool=16384

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "2"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```